# WPF - Json.NET: How do I deserialize multiple objects from Json and put it in an List?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, .net-core

File: data.json:

```
[
  {
    "Items": [
      {
        "Name": "Item 0"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Item 1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Item 2"
      }
    ] 
  }
]
```

Class:

```
public partial class ItemHandler : Page
{
    string itemsJson;
    public ItemHandler()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        itemsJson = JsonHandler.ReadItems();

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            // ???
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get each item from a string list by name, but i don't know how to deserialize one by one, I confused about Json.NET deserialization tutorials.

Comment: If working with visual studio you can use, special paste. Copy json to clipboard, then use ```Edit/Paste Special/Paste JSON as Classes```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
void Main()
{
    var json ="[{\"Items\":[{\"Name\":\"Item 0\"},{\"Name\":\"Item 1\"},{\"Name\":\"Item 2\"}]}]";

    var jD=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root[]>(json);

    foreach (var items in jD)
    {
        foreach (var item in items.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
    }

}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```